# Configuring Rails to generate the correct first line in development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.0.0. When I run `rails new test_app`, the generated file `test_app/config/environments/development.rb` always contains the first line:

`Rails.application.configure do`

The above line causes an undefined local variable error. It should be:

`TestApp::Application.configure do`

Is there a way to configure rails so that it always generates the correct name?

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue? I have Rails projects that all have this and work.

Comment: @Maran are you saying that this is the default behaviour of Rails, and not a misconfiguration in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1.1, I just created a new Rails app using the command `rails new test_app_rails_4-1-1`.  The top line of [the development.rb file](https://github.com/amorphid/test_app_rails_4-1-1/blob/master/config/environments/development.rb) is `Rails.application.configure do`, which is the correct syntax.

I just looked at a [the development.rb file](https://github.com/amorphid/hey_look_a_rails_app/blob/master/config/environments/development.rb) in a Rails 4.0.1 app.  The first line in that file is `HeyLookARailsApp::Application.configure do`.  So it seems like the syntax in Rails 4.1.1 is different that Rails 4.0.1.

Comment: Is this possibly because I was using Rails 4.1.1 while the tutorial called for Rails 4.0.5?

Comment: If you're following a tutorial that uses 4.0.5, and you're using something else, you can expect there to be differences.  Apparently this difference is one of them.